# Center button vertically while limiting height

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

On the left is a button, and on the right is an ImageView. I would like the button to be vertically centered with respect to the view, but not as tall as the view, say, 1/4 its current height.

[image: button and imageview]

Unfortunately, the only way I know how to center something vertically in RelativeLayout is with layout_alignTop/Bottom to the view, which stretches the button. How can I avoid this? XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/camera"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Tap to Take Picture"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cameraButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cameraButton"
        android:contentDescription="camera photo" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

(Side question: is there a way to get the view's height to be the same as its width without hardcoding 200dp? I suppose it can be done programatically, but would prefer XML)

Comment: *is there a way to get the view's height to be the same as its width without hardcoding*, yes but you must do that programatically, cannot do it with xml

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks, I'll look in to that

Comment: Using a `LinearLayout` may solve the problem.

Comment: Are you sure this xml produces that output? You have a vertical orientation and you don't specify that the imageview should be to the right of the button. The views should be below eachother, or in the worst case in the same place

Comment: copy paste error, edited. There are other things above and below which is why I'm using vertical

Comment: Sidenote: relativelayout doesn't use `android:orientation`, so you can leave that out. Forgot about that when i was typing my previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!

[image: Result layout]

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cameraButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Tap to Take Picture"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/camera"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:contentDescription="camera photo" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Judging from the comments above, I don't think OP wants a horizontal orientation, or change his layout to a linearlayout

Comment: This piece of code could be a part of a bigger layout. It does the job. Moreover, the question doesn't precise how it should be done.

Comment: *This piece of code could be a part of a bigger layout* that is exactly why you should try to not change it into something else. Maybe OP needs relativelayout functionality

Comment: You might be right, but still - this could be used as a part of bigger layout. Just include it in another layout.

Comment: True! We will let OP figure out what he needs

Comment: Using nested layouts always seems lame, but this may be all that works. Android layouting is not my favorite

Comment: @mjr Well sometimes there is no other way. We should avoid nested layouts. In this case it won't affect the performance too much since it can calculate the height in the first iteration (just take the 200dp of the inner ImageVIew).

Comment: Did the trick, thanks! alignTop/Bottom isn't used in horizontal LinearLayout though it seems